# Why am I getting variable errors with exec

Tags: javascript, regex

Me and my friend are trying to resolve this but we can't figure this out we found some posts that offer solutions on this error but we don't know how to apply it to our situation so basically the code is suppose to return all regex matches which is referring to

document.querySelector('#output-2').innerHTML= output;

We expect to see the id = values from a-g to output but the console is saying this

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token var
```

and that error is referencing to this line

```
while (var match = pattern.exec(string) !== null)
```

so why am I getting that error?

Here is my code

```js
var names= document.querySelectorAll('.name');

var text = new Array();
var strtext = '';
 
for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++){
var arlength = text.length;
text[arlength] = '['+names[i].getAttribute('id')+']';
}
strtext = text.join(' and ');
document.querySelector('#output-1').innerHTML= strtext;

//Show all the regex matches
var string= strtext;
var pattern= /\[(.*?)\]/ig;
var output = "";
while (var match = pattern.exec(string) !== null)
{
    output += match[1];
}
document.querySelector('#output-2').innerHTML = output;
```

```html
<p id='a' class='name'>Adam</p>
<p id='b' class='name'>Bob</p>
<p id='c' class='name'>Cane</p>
<p id='d' class='name'>Dan</p>
<p id='e' class='name'>Ed</p>
<p id='f' class='name'>Fred</p>
<p id='g' class='name'>Gene</p>

<p id='output-1'></p>
<p id='output-2'></p>
```

Comment: `while` expects an expression, while you're passing a statement there. Even if it worked - it would not do what you wanted, since `match` would be a boolean (thanks to operators precedence). To solve it - don't assign in the loop condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`var` indicates the *initialization* of a new variable, and such initializations are only permitted as *standalone statements* - variable initialization cannot be parsed as an expression, and the inside of an `while(` only accepts an expression (something that evaluates to a value). (in contrast to an expression, a statement *does* something, like initialize a value, or carry out an `if` / `then` block)

Initialize `match` *outside* of the `while` condition instead.

You also need to put parentheses around the `match = pattern.exec(string)` expression in order to properly compare it to `null`, otherwise you'll be assigning the result of `pattern.exec(string) !== null` (that is, a *boolean*) to `output`, which isn't what you want:

```js
var names= document.querySelectorAll('.name');

var text = new Array();
var strtext = '';
 
for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++){
var arlength = text.length;
text[arlength] = '['+names[i].getAttribute('id')+']';
}
strtext = text.join(' and ');
document.querySelector('#output-1').innerHTML= strtext;

//Show all the regex matches
var string= strtext;
var pattern= /\[(.*?)\]/ig;
var output = "";
var match;
while ((match = pattern.exec(string)) !== null)
{
    output += match[1];
}
document.querySelector('#output-2').innerHTML = output;
```

```html
<p id='a' class='name'>Adam</p>
<p id='b' class='name'>Bob</p>
<p id='c' class='name'>Cane</p>
<p id='d' class='name'>Dan</p>
<p id='e' class='name'>Ed</p>
<p id='f' class='name'>Fred</p>
<p id='g' class='name'>Gene</p>

<p id='output-1'></p>
<p id='output-2'></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the variable declaration outside of the `while` condition, and use parentheses to override default operator precedence (logical beats assignment):

```js
var names= document.querySelectorAll('.name');

var text = new Array();
var strtext = '';
 
for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++){
var arlength = text.length;
text[arlength] = '['+names[i].getAttribute('id')+']';
}
strtext = text.join(' and ');
document.querySelector('#output-1').innerHTML= strtext;

//Show all the regex matches
var string= strtext;
var pattern= /\[(.*?)\]/ig;
var output = "";
var match;
while ((match = pattern.exec(string)) !== null)
{
    output += match[1];
}
document.querySelector('#output-2').innerHTML = output;
```

```html
<p id='a' class='name'>Adam</p>
<p id='b' class='name'>Bob</p>
<p id='c' class='name'>Cane</p>
<p id='d' class='name'>Dan</p>
<p id='e' class='name'>Ed</p>
<p id='f' class='name'>Fred</p>
<p id='g' class='name'>Gene</p>

<p id='output-1'></p>
<p id='output-2'></p>
```

Comment: Thank you Robby Cornelissen for your reply. According to the page CertainPerformance beat you a min before you posted an answer so I will go based on first come first served answer so thanks for replying as well so I'm going to give you a point for taking the time in trying to help me out.

Comment: Actually, he posted 41 seconds after me, but feel free to accept whichever. (FYI, you can see the timestamps if you hover over the "answered xx mins ago" text.)